# OpenConnect VPN taking a long time to show the dialog box

Tags: networking, vpn

The VPN I connect to (a Cisco AnyConnect VPN) normally pops up the connection dialog box for username and password (I have two factor auth) very quickly, but today it took a really long time (minutes).  Once the dialog showed up, I was able to log in and everything seems to be working fine, but that long wait is disconcerting and abnormal.

I installed xubuntu-desktop via apt yesterday, if that helps pinpoint what changed.

Other useful bits of info:

- Ubuntu 14.10
- 64-bit
- VPN configured through NetworkManager